# File download with cordova file transfer plugin for android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, file-transfer

I am using cordova file transfer plugin to download jpg images from remote server, everything seems right but it doesn't work,I get the error code 3. 
Here is my js code:

```
      var uri = encodeURI(serverUrl),
      dir = encodeURI(cordova.file.dataDirectory+'images/'+file),
      ft = new FileTransfer();
      ft.download(uri, dir,
          function (fileEntry) {
             alert('Downloaded!');
          },
          function (error) {
             alert('Download error'+ error.code);
          },false,
          {
              headers: {
                  "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
          }
      });
```

and here is my php code

```
  //Donwload images from server
      $app->GET('/downloadMedia/{filename}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
          $file = 'upload/images/'.$args['filename'];
         if(file_exists($file))
        {
          $response ->withHeader('Content-Description', 'File Transfer')
        ->withHeader('Content-Type','application/octet-stream')
        ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="'.basename($file).'"')
        ->withHeader('Expires', '0')
        ->withHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
        ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate')
        ->withHeader('Pragma', 'public')
        ->withHeader('Content-Length', filesize($file));
         readfile($file);
         exit;
        }
      });
```

Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it was related to my server url not to the transfer plugin as i thought